# Kotlin - Serialization and data class with `is` prefixed methods

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data class representing a role of a user.

```
data class UserRole(
    val entity: Entity,                            
    val role: Role,
    val entityId: String
) {

    fun isAdmin() = role == Role.ADMIN
}
```

When I do serialize this, I see in addition to `entity`, `role` and `entityId`, I do also get `isAdmin` in my JSON. How can I stop this?

FYI - This is a KMM class present in `commonMain` and I do use Firebase for storing it in DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to serialize/deserialize a specific property, annotate it with `@Exclude`. So:

```
data class UserRole(
    val entity: Entity,                            
    val role: Role,
    val entityId: String
) {
    @Exclude
    fun isAdmin() = role == Role.ADMIN
}
```

Comment: What's the iOS alternative to @Exclude? As this class is part of KMP, I need to define for both Android and iOS.

Comment: I don't immediately see an equivalent for iOS in the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes)), but it might be part of the Codable implementation there, which I'm not an expert at. If you can't find it yourself, I recommend opening a separate question for iOS, so that experts on *that* can help.